# How can I build cpan modules on 64-bit windows server 2012?

Tags: perl, cpan, activestate

How can I build cpan modules on 64-bit windows server 2012?

This is the error message:

```
It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW64 gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

Downloading pan packlist...done
ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW64

It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW64 has failed.  You will not
be able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check
your internet connection and your proxy settings!
```

Comment: You can use perl package manager. ppm. Refer http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl

Comment: ppm's coverage of modules varies, but might be enough to cover OP's needs. It is a *lot* easier than getting CPAN to compile packages on 64-bit Windows (which is possible, I have done so, but was 2 years ago and I don't have notes in order to construct an answer here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) (64bit)! This version of Perl comes with a gcc compiler and is working on 64bit systems, you can download modeules from CPAN and compile them if needed.